# How could I take only the items in an array of objects that match the users input

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sorting

I have a response body that looks something like this:

```
        {
            "id": "provider-a7d49a99-53c0-4b7c-9be3-8b9efc828f1b",
            "fullName": "Dr. Tim Lucca, FSE",
            "firstName": "Tim",
            "lastName": "Lucca",
            "prefix": "Dr.",
            "suffix": "FSE",
            "phone": "(303) 520-4571",
            "state": "CO",
            "doseSpotID": 185012,
            "active": "active",
            "capabilities": {
                "demographic": [
                    "adolescent",
                    "adult",
                    "child"
                ],
                "geographic": [
                    "CO",
                    "TX"
                ],
                "linguistic": [
                    "english",
                    "spanish"
                ],
                "credentialedPayors": null
            },
            "invitePending": false
        },
        {
            "id": "provider-450de310-fcb5-4e71-9d72-b6b320b2eb0a",
            "fullName": "Mr Doc Torr",
            "firstName": "Doc",
            "lastName": "Torr",
            "prefix": "Mr",
            "suffix": "",
            "phone": "(303) 520-4571",
            "state": "CO",
            "doseSpotID": 186856,
            "active": "active",
            "capabilities": {
                "demographic": [
                    "adult",
                    "adolescent",
                    "child"
                ],
                "geographic": [
                    "CO",
                    "TX"
                ],
                "linguistic": [
                    "english"
                ],
                "credentialedPayors": null
            },
            "invitePending": false
        }
    ]
```

I have a search field for the user that they are able to search by `fullName`, `phone`, and `geographic`. Im trying to understand how to sort the list returned and display only the items in the list that have a match for the users input. What would be a good way to sort through the array of objects and creating an array of matches for the users search? Right now my component is just displaying all of the items returned.

Comment: You may not need to sort. Just use filter

Comment: A good way would be to only response matching items.

Comment: If i used .filter Im not sure what the inside of my function would look like. If items is my array of object I would make something like `let list = items.filter( i => ...)` I only see examples online for checking length and not checking if any values match the string entered. Any advice on this?

Answer (score 0):

for an exect match i would do this

```
let to_sort =
    [
        {
            "id": "provider-a7d49a99-53c0-4b7c-9be3-8b9efc828f1b",
            "fullName": "Dr. Tim Lucca, FSE",
            "firstName": "Tim",
            "lastName": "Lucca",
            "prefix": "Dr.",
            "suffix": "FSE",
            "phone": "(303) 520-4571",
            "state": "CO",
            "doseSpotID": 185012,
            "active": "active",
            "capabilities": {
                "demographic": [
                    "adolescent",
                    "adult",
                    "child"
                ],
                "geographic": [
                    "CO",
                    "TX"
                ],
                "linguistic": [
                    "english",
                    "spanish"
                ],
                "credentialedPayors": null
            },
            "invitePending": false
        },
        {
            "id": "provider-450de310-fcb5-4e71-9d72-b6b320b2eb0a",
            "fullName": "Mr Doc Torr",
            "firstName": "Doc",
            "lastName": "Torr",
            "prefix": "Mr",
            "suffix": "",
            "phone": "(303) 520-4571",
            "state": "CO",
            "doseSpotID": 186856,
            "active": "active",
            "capabilities": {
                "demographic": [
                    "adult",
                    "adolescent",
                    "child"
                ],
                "geographic": [
                    "CO",
                    "TX"
                ],
                "linguistic": [
                    "english"
                ],
                "credentialedPayors": null
            },
            "invitePending": false
        }
    ]
let user_fullName = 'Dr. Tim Lucca, FSE'
let phone = '(303) 520-4571'
let geographic = 'CO'
let result = to_sort.filter((obj)=>{
    if(obj.fullName !== user_fullName){
        return false
    }
    if(obj.phone !== phone){
        return false
    }
    if(!obj.capabilities.geographic.includes(geographic)){
        return false
    }
    return true
});
```

to check if 1 of the properties is the same (not gonna put the data in is its quite big)

```
let user_fullName = 'Dr. Tim Lucca, FSE'
let phone = '(303) 520-4571'
let geographic = 'CO'
let result = to_sort.filter((obj)=>{
    if(obj.fullName === user_fullName || obj.phone === phone || obj.capabilities.geographic.includes(geographic)){
        return true
    }
    return false
});
```

in both cases result is an array of objects which have met the criteria